# Struct vars size defined by macro returns "this operator is not allowed in a constant expression"

Tags: c, struct, c-preprocessor

Any solution to this compiler ERROR?

```
#define TYPE_TOTAL 10
#define MAX_SIZE 20

#define NBITS2(n) ((n&2)?1:0)
#define NBITS4(n) ((n&(0xC))?(2+NBITS2(n>>2)):(NBITS2(n)))
#define NBITS8(n) ((n&0xF0)?(4+NBITS4(n>>4)):(NBITS4(n)))
#define NBITS16(n) ((n&0xFF00)?(8+NBITS8(n>>8)):(NBITS8(n)))
#define NBITS32(n) ((n&0xFFFF0000)?(16+NBITS16(n>>16)):(NBITS16(n)))
#define NBITS(n) (n==0?0:NBITS32(n)+1)

typedef struct StatsEntry_s
{
    uint32 type:NBITS(TYPE_TOTAL);   
    uint32 subtype:NBITS(MAX_SIZE);         
}  StatsEntry_t;
```

> uint32 type:NBITS(TYPE_TOTAL);
>   "this operator is not allowed in a constant expression".

Comment: Well have you tried simplifying one of your #defines and slowly adding the operators in until it breaks?

Comment: I take it that the compiler is right and the ternary conditional is not allowed in a compile time constant. (Actually, the compiler *is always* right!). That said, you can write `#define NBITS2(n) ((n&2)>>1`) which should work. Edit: I didn't see that it was complaining about NBITS which calls all others... perhaps there is a similar remedy for all of them but I'm not sure.

Comment: In fact, C does not forbid a constant expression from including a ternary operator, and GCC permits it, as I verified on a much simplified version of the code presented.

Comment: In fact, GCC accepts the whole original code, as everything I can see indicates a compiler conforming to C99 or C2011 must do.  I am therefore inclined to answer the question with "get a conforming compiler".  Since your compiler *does not* conform, it's hard to say what other answer we could confidently make.

Comment: @John Hmm... interesting.

Comment: Digging deeper, the C99 formal syntax for a `constant-expression`, such as is required in a bitfield declaration, explicitly *permits* the ternary operator, the equality operator, the addition operator, the arithmetic-and operator, and the right-shift operator, as well as others not used in the OP's code.  Some operators that otherwise would be allowed are forbidden by constraints expressed in the standard, but not any of the ones I named.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, a constant-expression is just a conditional-expression (6.6) which explicitly can be a ternary operator expression (6.5.15). I see that neither gcc nor a modern (online) VS C++ compiler has problems with that code, so I'm not sure now where the OP's problem is.

Comment: Side issue: Rather than `(n&0xFFFF0000)`, use `(n>&0xFFFF)`.  This allows your method to extend to `NBITS64(n)` and `NBITS128(n)`

Answer (score 1):

Edit: John Bollinger commented correctly that your macros are actually valid constant expressions; indeed the code compiles and runs with a gcc 4.9.3, VS C++ (http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) as well as clang 3.5.1. We are not sure why you have problems -- which compiler are you using? But anyway, if you are stuck with a compiler that can't do that:

I think you can substitute the conditions with arithmetic, the way I suggested in my comment for the simplest macro. For example for `NBITS4(n)`:
The original is

```
#define NBITS4(n) ((n&(0xC))?(2+NBITS2(n>>2)):(NBITS2(n)))
```

which makes two things dependent on the 0xC bits, the bit shift count and adding 2. Let's see. If there is a match we want to add 2: (n&(0xC) != 0)*2 should be 2 if a bit is set. For the bit shift we consider that n>>0 is (I think) n, so that we can again compute 0 or 2 dependent on n&0xC the same way as before. That should yield

```
#define NBITS4(n) (((n)&(0xC) != 0)*2+NBITS2((n)>>((n)&(0xC) != 0)*2))
```

I'm not sure whether that's the easiest way, and I didn't test it, but it should be a start.

A technicality: Always bracket your macro arguments; defines are text replacement and can expand to surprising expressions.

On a general note: Computations are much faster than jumps on modern CPUs. Sometimes using booleans as numbers instead of as conditions for branching gives surprising performance gains. The downside is that it can be absolutely unreadable, like here.

Comment: FWIW, the ternary operator is often implemented without a jump.

Comment: @johnbollinger: since this is a constant expression and therefore evaluated by the compiler, I doubt whether the possible jump-free implementation is relevant. In the wider context, +1 with the additional note that compilers might also be able to optimize certain ternaries using whatever optimization tricks they have available.

Comment: @rici In the compile-time constant the only effect of a ternary may be on compile time ;-).

Comment: Yes, that's why I think efficiency considerations are irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

You could redefine your macros without the ternary operator.  This is only good up to 255 but could be extended easily:

```
#define NBITS2(n) (((!(n&2))*(n&1))|(n&2))
#define NBITS4(n) (((!(n&4))*NBITS2(n))|(((n&4)>>2)*3))
#define NBITS8(n) (((!(n&8))*NBITS4(n))|(((n&8)>>3)*4))
#define NBITS16(n) (((!(n&16))*NBITS8(n))|(((n&16)>>4)*5))
#define NBITS32(n) (((!(n&32))*NBITS16(n))|(((n&32)>>5)*6))
#define NBITS64(n) (((!(n&64))*NBITS32(n))|(((n&64)>>6)*7))
#define NBITS(n) (((!(n&128))*NBITS64(n))|(((n&128)>>7)*8))
```